# JavaScript group anagram performance

Tags: javascript

I created an algorithm to create lists of anagrams

The input is `["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]`

Then, the output should be:
`[["eat","tea","ate"],["tan","nat"],["bat"]]`

Each array is words that are anagram.

My solution is:

```
function group(input) {
    let result = [];
    if(input.length === 0){
        return result;
    }

    for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        let check = true;
        for(let j=0; j<result.length; j++){
            if(result[j].includes(input[i])){
                check = false;
            }
        }
        if(check){
            result.push(checkAnagrams(input, i)); 
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function checkAnagrams(aStr, i){
    let anagrams = [];
    anagrams.push(aStr[i]);
    for(let j=0; j<aStr.length; j++){
        if(i !== j){
            if(isAnagram(aStr[i], aStr[j])){
                anagrams.push(aStr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return anagrams;
}

function isAnagram(str1, str2) {
    // split => string into array
    // sort => sort the array
    // join => string to array
    // trim => remove any space
    const string1 = str1.split("").sort().join().trim();
    const string2 = str2.split("").sort().join().trim();
    if(string1 === string2){
        return true;
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

I know it works, but I was wondering if there is a better way to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code written by [dariosicily](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/203649/dariosicily) I made a bit of changes to it.

`const key` could be declared outside with `let`, it improves a bit the performance. The inside of the loop, could be changed by:

```js
function anagrams(input) {
    const map = new Map();
    let key;
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        if (map.has(key = [...input[i]].sort().join(''))) 
            map.get(key).push(input[i]);
        else map.set(key, [input[i]]);
    }
    return [...map.values()];
}
```

The assignment of variables has a quite notorious performance impact (when the input is great enough).

Note: I thought of writing it as a comment to dario but it was big.

Comment: Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Could you provide sources to this claim? Conceptionally a `const` should be preferred here over `let` because its a different key in each loop and not a single key that is changing. Considering the complexity of the logic inside the loop, I doubt that "reusing" a variable changes the performance noticeably.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review, the complexity of your code can be reduced using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object having as keys sorted lexicographically strings and as values arrays of their anagrams. For example you will have the following couples key - value starting from your input:

```
key = "aet"  value = ["eat","tea","ate"]
key = "ant"  value = ["tan","nat"]
key = "abt"  value = ["bat"]
```

So you can define a function `anagrams` like this:

```
function anagrams(input) {
    const map = new Map();

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        const key = [...input[i]].sort().join('');
        const value = map.has(key) ? map.get(key) : [];
        value.push(input[i]);
        map.set(key, value);
    }

    return [...map.values()];
}

/*below it will print the expected result*/
console.log(anagrams(["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]));
```

I just used the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to expand the string `input[i]` to array of characters and after I sort it to obtain the corrisponding key in the map. After I add it to the array of strings associated to the key and finally I return the map values as an array.

Note: I'm a javascript beginner so every hint or criticism about my answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Consider not using spread](https://hackernoon.com/3-javascript-performance-mistakes-you-should-stop-doing-ebf84b9de951)

Comment: @KooiInc Thanks for your advice and the link, I will use spread just for simple exercises like this; it is quite surprising to find a 10x difference between one construct and another one applied to the same task.